# How to switch component in angular 5 like template?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to switch component in angular like switching templates based on user roles?:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-order-select',
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="storage.getUserRole() == 'admin'">{require('./order-select.component.html')} </div>
        <div *ngIf="storage.getUserRole() == 'legal'"> {require('./order-select.component-legal.html')} </div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./order-select.component.css']
})
export class OrderSelectComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

My app route:

```
{
    path: 'orders/select',
    component: OrderSelectComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a resolver to redirect to another wrote based on user roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
<div id="roleDependantContent">
    <app-component-admin *ng-if="storage.getUserRole() == 'admin'"/>
    <app-component-user *ng-if="storage.getUserRole() == 'user'"/>
</div>
```

It will only load the component fitting your user's role.